# Как узнать id фотки/видео в телеграмме

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я хочу чтоб мой бот присылал фотки/видео в канал при вводе команды.
Но я не знаю как узнать id  файла.
Использую aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Если отправляешь с диска своего:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('tests/test.png', 'rb'))
```

Если отправляешь через Url:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo='https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png')
```